# How to provide required privilege for www-data user in php

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, ubuntu

I am trying to execute a shell script which will copy certain folders and files from one location to another.

But I am struggling with a very basic problem - ie; I cannot copy folders or files when I call this script from php. Whereas the same script works perfect from terminal. Is it because that, from terminal when I execute this script, the user has has enough privileges to copy/create files/folders , where as when the script is called from php, the user does not have enough privileges?

For php, `shell_exec('whoami');` says the user is www-data

What should I do, in order that, I have enough privileges to do the create and copy operations from php user www-data

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
username ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

in your sudoers file, In `/etc/sudoers`, you can also use `visudo` command to edit that file.