# What permissions to set for www-data to execute script as root

Tags: php, lamp

I am trying to run multiple different ruby scripts (which requires sudo to execute properly) via php commands. since the default user when running in PHP is www-data (which doesnt have sudo permissions) I apparently cant run the scripts. I found a potential solution here: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592699/how-to-provide-required-privilege-for-www-data-user-in-php) but I was wondering if there was a simple way to do this for dozens of files (not just one)

Comment: Why not configure sudo to allow the www-data user to run those programs?

Comment: Do you mean set: www-data ALL =(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL in /etc/sudoers?

Comment: You would probably want to give www-data the ability to run as ruby user via sudo, not root.

Comment: Preferably you'd configure it to allow just specific commands, not ALL. Giving your webserver the ability to run certain commands as root is risky enough; giving it full root access is a very bad idea.